# fetch section of a string from column in python

Tags: python

I'm working with a database that looks something like this:

```
Review_ID   Rating  Year_Month  Reviewer_Location
670772142   4   2019-4  Australia
670682799   4   2020-5  Philippines
670623270   4   missing United Arab Emirates
670607911   4   missing Australia
670607296   4   2014-11 United Kingdom
670591897   3   2016-12 Singapore
670585330   5   2019-4  India
```

This is my first time doing anything with python and I don't have complete clarity of simple syntax.

My goal is to separate months from 'year-month' column by fetching all characters after the symbol '-' in the string and store them into a different column (unless the value of the string is 'missing'. In which case, it is not considered at all.) I've tried multiple things one of them being:

```html
yf=df['Year_Month']

while yf!='missing'
    if '-' in yf:
        store[0]=i
        i+=1
        store[1]=(i)
        df['Month'] = store
    else:
        i+=1
store
```

That doesn't work at all. This is just what I was messing around with now but I did get close to a working code but I just cant figure out how to get rid of the 'missing' data.

The question that I'm ultimately trying to solve is "Which period of the year is the peak time for visitor to visit each theme park" so please consider that I have to plot the results in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `str.replace` here:

```
df['Year']  = df['Year_Month'].str.replace('-.*$', '');
df['Month'] = df['Year_Month'].str.replace('^\d+-', '');
```

Note that since the string value `missing` does not match either regex pattern, in this case a missing `Year_Month` value would assign `missing` to both the year and month columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = {'Year_Month':['2019-4','2020-5','missing','missing','2014-11','2016-12','2019-4']}

d = pd.DataFrame(df)

for ym in df['Year_Month']:
    if ym != 'missing':
        year,month = ym.split('-')
        print(year,month)
```